# Is it possible to decode a NSKeyedArchived collection containing unknown objects

Tags: ios, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver, nssecurecoding

I have a collection of objects with different classes A, B, and C (all share a common superclass):

```
// Encoded collection
@[A, B, C]
```

This collection gets archived and unarchived via NSCoding.
**Is there a way to partially unarchive this collection if one of the classes has since been removed from the project**?

It seems `decodeObjectForKey:` fails and returns a `nil` object when it encounters an object it can't decode. Is there a way to instead only get what is able to be decoded? I understand why this behavior makes sense for an object but not for a collection.

```
// Expected decoding when A class definition is missing:
@[B, C]

// Actual:
nil
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class name and the class that you want to use instead are known then you can use the [`setClass:forClassName:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/setClass:forClassName:) method of `NSKeyedUnArchiver` to specify a translation, so you could use something like `[unarchiver setClass:MySuperClass.class forClassName:@"C"]`

Comment: What if it's not a migration but a hard depreciation with a removal of the Class being unarchived? Could I attempt to `setClass` using the the removed classes superclass?

Comment: Yes, that is what I have shown in my answer - `MySuperClass` will be instantiated for any `Class C` objects in the archive

Comment: Is there a way to do this without knowing the specific classes that may not be recognized? My issue is with older builds receiving an archive with an object from a newer build which uses a class the older build won't recognize.

Comment: No.  You either need to ensure that your newer code explicitly handles older archives by adding a translation when you remove the deprecated class or simply keep the deprecated classes around but don't use them; Backward compatibility is why use of deprecated APIs is typically a warning and not an error

Comment: Okay, thank you, that makes sense. Sounds like what I want to do isn't possible with a collection. (._.)